# Accessing attributes from rails setter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am kind of stuck trying to access (read) an attribute from a custom setter in Rails:

```
def password=(new_password)

  puts self.firstname # returns nil

  # Do other checks here before setting a hashed SCrypt password

end
```

The firstname is defined on the (user) object, however calling the firstname will not yield the value set. I need to read various attributes from the custom setter to do password checks up against firstname, lastname and email address.

Comment: This is probably not the answer you're hoping for, but I would either a) user an auth gem like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or b) copy the auth strategy in [Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). I would personally do Devise, but neither way is terribly time-consuming.

Comment: Sadly Devise is not an option for us.

Comment: Then I'd try copying Michael Hartl's technique.

Comment: Could you post a link to the relevant page/section of his page?

Comment: Not a direct answer either: A great alternative to Devise is [Clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance).

Comment: Rather than use an external gem as others have advised I'd suggest watching the Railscast for rolling your own auth.  It's so simple you don't really need these huge libraries: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Comment: The problem if I am reading your question right, is that your use of "self" in this context is incorrect.  See my answer below.

Comment: @LasseLaursen Chapter 8: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#top

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the corresponding getter method?

```
def password
  @password
end
```

Or if it's a really simple getter/setter pair just

```
:attr_accessor password
```

Update on your comment: so you're wanting to do something other than just set the attribute in the setter?

So obviously I have to advise against that.  However you can just do something like:

```
def password=(new_password)
  some_method(new_password)
  @password = new_password
end
```

This will pass the new_password method out of the setter, allowing you to do other things with it, before setting the instance variable to the new value.

If you are trying to access the firstname attribute within the password setter, as in your example, you can do it this way:

```
def password=(new_password)
  some_method(firstname)
  @password = new_password
end
```

You don't use self to call the getter method.

Comment: Yes I have a getter method. What I am looking for is a way to access the user.firstname attribute from within the setter method for the password.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't seem to work. I can't access the firstname variable inside the setter method - and therefor can't pass it to some_method either.

Comment: You'll need to post the code for where your user fields are being set as it is shooting in the dark without being able to see that. Can you just post the class so we can see what it looks like as the code in the answer is right.

Comment: I'm assuming this password= method is in the User class ...you need to post the context to be able to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems to be an issue with my app somewhere. I just did a minimal test application that works fine:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def password
    password ||= SCrypt::Password.new(password_hash)
  end

  def password=(new_password)

    logger.info 'DEBUG: self.lastname: ' + self.lastname.to_s

    self.password_hash = SCrypt::Password.create(new_password, :key_len => 512, :salt_size => 32)

  end

end
```

In console it works fine:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
2.0.0-p0 :001 > u = User.new
 => #<User id: nil, firstname: nil, lastname: nil, password_hash: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.0.0-p0 :002 > u.lastname = "Some Lastname"
 => "Some Lastname"
2.0.0-p0 :003 > u.password = 'test'
DEBUG: self.lastname: Some Lastname
 => "test"
```

So it seems to be some issue related to a gem / something / somewhere in the application and not a Rails specific problem. Apologies to the list.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the params matters here based on what I have observed.

⚠️ Notice the order of `:firstname` and `:password` when passing.

If you're using `params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :password)` and then passing it to your setters via `.new` or `=setter` methods. Then you can always access `self.firstname` in your `password=` setter method because you `firstname` got set first and it's available to access for next setters.

However, if you have `params.require(:user).permit(:password, :firstname)` then your password setter method cannot access `self.firstname`.